How can I make DateEntry widget bigger (font and button) in ttkbootstrap?
I wanted the widget to be proportional to the size of other widgets in my app (I used a larger font).
I tried:
style = Style()
style.configure('Calendar.TCalendar', font=(None, 30))

but it doesn't work. I also tried using tkcalendar but it doesn't work with ttkbootstrap.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
